# Coordinates of a button on storyboard are not the same as the position of the button on the simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I was having a problem with the position of a button.

On the storyboard. I adjusted the coordinates to a certain position with the button appearing correctly on the storyboard view controller.

I combined this with some runtime attributes adjusting border attributes but nothing else along with more adjustments in this code in the swift file for the view controller as below.

```
extension UIButton {

 func setUpLayer(sampleButton: UIButton?) {

  sampleButton?.tintColor =  UIColor.white

  sampleButton!.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    sampleButton!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor

  sampleButton!.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0


  sampleButton!.layer.shadowRadius =  3.0


    sampleButton!.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor


  sampleButton!.layer.shadowOpacity =  0.3

 }

}
```

I may have some repetition but I do not see how this would affect the position.

On the simulator, these buttons which are changed using this extension have a completely incorrect position. I have no idea why

P.S. I know this is poorly formatted. Apologies

Can anyone explain?

Comment: maybe try setting  `sampleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Comment: Are you using constraints?